# Assigning a variable based on an input condition

Tags: rust

I am writing a function in rust which accepts a reference to a one-dimensional `ndarray`. As part of the function I need to check if the length of the input array reference is a power of two. If this is not the case then a new array must be created with the identical elements of the input array, zero padded until the length is a power of two. I have a function `zero_pad` which takes the array reference and does the check and padding if required.

The problem I am encountering is how to assign the correct array. For example imagine I have some uninitialized variable `_x` which will be assigned to the whichever array is to be used (the original or the padded array). The code that I have essentially hacked to get this function is very messy and non-rustacean as I would like it to be clean and ideally efficient.

```
pub fn func<T>(x: &Array1<T>) -> Array1<Complex<T>> 
{
    let N = x.len();
    let zero = T::from_f64(0.0).unwrap();
    let opt = zero_pad(x); // zero_pad does the check and returns an option with None if no padding and Some(x) with new padded array if required

    let tmp: Array1<T>;
    let _x: &Array1<T>;
    let mut padded: bool = false;
    match opt{
        None => {
            padded = false;
            tmp = array![zero]; // Initialise just to satisfy compiler 
        },
        Some(arr) => {
            tmp = arr;
            padded = true;
        }
    }
    if padded {
        _x = &tmp;
    }
    else {
        _x = x;
    }
```

Could only help me get this desired functionality. I feel as though my best best would be to write a macro which calls a function that does this check for me and essentially passes the correct array into the `func` function which would simplify things but I thought I'd ask for peoples thoughts/suggestions in case I'm going about it the wrong way.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: please make a [mcve] that include everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that you can return values from a match expression.

```rs
let tmp: Array1<T>;
let _x = match zero_pad(x) {
    Some(new) => {
        tmp = new;
        &tmp
    }
    None => &x,
};
```

Comment: Thanks ! Somehow I must have missed that all this time haha